# Windows 2012r2 w/ sql server 2012 Broken

Tags: windows, sql-server

Sql server 2012 was working yesterday.

But then windows update happened today at 4AM 4/12/2017 and now it seems like the sql server is timing out and such...

In addition none of the SQL integration services projects are running till competition. may have something to do with timeouts.

Anyone else having this issue after windows update? If so is there any way to resolve what the real issue is if no one else is having the issue?

EDIT: 
Rebooted twice and restarted service twice.

EDIT MORE INFO: (UPDATES LISTED)

[Windows updates installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VhVA.png)

```
    Date,Source,Severity,Message
04/12/2017 10:42:53,spid55,Unknown,External dump process return code 0x20000001.<nl/>External dump process returned no errors.
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000121D2A808
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* Short Stack Dump
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* *******************************************************************************
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,*
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,*             truncate table tmpSTPOTrack
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* Input Buffer 76 bytes -
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,*
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* Latch timeout
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,*
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,*   04/12/17 10:42:44 spid 55
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* BEGIN STACK DUMP:
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,*
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,* *******************************************************************************
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0019.txt
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,**Dump thread - spid = 0<c/> EC = 0x000000086B61EAC0
04/12/2017 10:42:44,spid55,Unknown,Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
04/12/2017 10:42:43,spid54,Unknown,Timeout occurred while waiting for latch: class 'LOG_MANAGER'<c/> id 000000086FD80B98<c/> type 4<c/> Task 0x000000086D766CA8 : 0<c/> waittime 600 seconds<c/> flags 0x1a<c/> owning task 0x000000086D9EF088. Continuing to wait.
04/12/2017 10:42:43,spid55,Unknown,Timeout occurred while waiting for latch: class 'LOG_MANAGER'<c/> id 000000086FD80B98<c/> type 4<c/> Task 0x000000086D7664E8 : 0<c/> waittime 600 seconds<c/> flags 0x1a<c/> owning task 0x000000086D9EF088. Continuing to wait.
04/12/2017 10:30:41,spid69,Unknown,Autogrow of file 'POSI_PIM5_log' in database 'POSI_PIM5' was cancelled by user or timed out after 3789 milliseconds.  Use ALTER DATABASE to set a smaller FILEGROWTH value for this file or to explicitly set a new file size.
04/12/2017 10:30:37,spid75,Unknown,Autogrow of file 'POSI_PIM5_log' in database 'POSI_PIM5' was cancelled by user or timed out after 30016 milliseconds.  Use ALTER DATABASE to set a smaller FILEGROWTH value for this file or to explicitly set a new file size.
04/12/2017 10:29:45,spid68,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=12.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 2 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].1).
04/12/2017 10:29:45,spid68,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=12.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 2 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].1).
04/12/2017 10:29:45,spid68,Unknown,AppDomain 2 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].1) created.
04/12/2017 10:26:35,Server,Unknown,Software Usage Metrics is enabled.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2014.120.4100' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_sqlagent_notify'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
04/12/2017 10:26:15,spid51,Unknown,Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
04/12/2017 10:26:14,spid7s,Unknown,Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:14,spid24s,Unknown,Service Broker manager has started.
04/12/2017 10:26:14,spid24s,Unknown,The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
04/12/2017 10:26:14,spid24s,Unknown,The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
04/12/2017 10:26:13,spid9s,Unknown,Starting up database 'tempdb'.
04/12/2017 10:26:13,spid21s,Unknown,Recovery completed for database POSI_PIM5 (database ID 7) in 1 second(s) (analysis 237 ms<c/> redo 114 ms<c/> undo 4 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:13,spid21s,Unknown,Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'POSI_PIM5' (7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:13,spid21s,Unknown,1 transactions rolled back in database 'POSI_PIM5' (7:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:12,spid21s,Unknown,6 transactions rolled forward in database 'POSI_PIM5' (7:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:11,spid19s,Unknown,Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'PIM5_Operational' (8). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:11,spid19s,Unknown,0 transactions rolled back in database 'PIM5_Operational' (8:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:11,spid17s,Unknown,Recovery completed for database msdb (database ID 4) in 1 second(s) (analysis 24 ms<c/> redo 85 ms<c/> undo 93 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid9s,Unknown,Clearing tempdb database.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid17s,Unknown,Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'msdb' (4). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid19s,Unknown,9 transactions rolled forward in database 'PIM5_Operational' (8:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid17s,Unknown,0 transactions rolled back in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid17s,Unknown,164 transactions rolled forward in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid18s,Unknown,0 transactions rolled back in database 'ReportServer' (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid20s,Unknown,0 transactions rolled back in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid18s,Unknown,1 transactions rolled forward in database 'ReportServer' (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid9s,Unknown,Starting up database 'model'.
04/12/2017 10:26:10,spid20s,Unknown,1 transactions rolled forward in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid9s,Unknown,The resource database build version is 12.00.4487. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid23s,Unknown,Starting up database 'PositiveUsers'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid9s,Unknown,Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid22s,Unknown,Starting up database 'SSISDB'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid18s,Unknown,Starting up database 'ReportServer'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid19s,Unknown,Starting up database 'PIM5_Operational'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid17s,Unknown,Starting up database 'msdb'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid20s,Unknown,Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,spid21s,Unknown,Starting up database 'POSI_PIM5'.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'POS-PIM5-APP'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'POSI_PIM5'. [CLIENT: 192.168.2.237]
04/12/2017 10:26:09,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456<c/> Severity: 14<c/> State: 38.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid14s,Unknown,A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,Server,Unknown,The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/pos-web-sql2.POSITIVE.LOCAL:1433 ] for the SQL Server service.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,Server,Unknown,The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/pos-web-sql2.POSITIVE.LOCAL ] for the SQL Server service.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,Server,Unknown,SQL Server is attempting to register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid13s,Unknown,SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,Server,Unknown,Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,Server,Unknown,Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
04/12/2017 10:26:08,Server,Unknown,Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid13s,Unknown,Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\sql\query ].
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid13s,Unknown,Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid13s,Unknown,Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid13s,Unknown,Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid13s,Unknown,A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
04/12/2017 10:26:08,spid7s,Unknown,Server name is 'POS-WEB-SQL2'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:07,spid7s,Unknown,SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
04/12/2017 10:26:06,spid7s,Unknown,SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:06,spid7s,Unknown,SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:05,Server,Unknown,Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
04/12/2017 10:26:04,Server,Unknown,CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,spid7s,Unknown,Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,spid7s,Unknown,0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,spid7s,Unknown,28 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,spid7s,Unknown,Starting up database 'master'.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,Server,Unknown,Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,Server,Unknown,Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:03,Server,Unknown,The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
04/12/2017 10:26:03,Server,Unknown,This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 2224 at 4/12/2017 10:06:18 AM (local) 4/12/2017 2:06:18 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:01,Server,Unknown,Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Detected 32668 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket<c/> 8 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Command Line Startup Parameters:<nl/>     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Registry startup parameters: <nl/>    -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf<nl/>     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG<nl/>    -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Authentication mode is MIXED.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,System Manufacturer: 'Dell Inc.'<c/> System Model: 'PowerEdge R730'.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,Server process ID is 2212.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,All rights reserved.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,(c) Microsoft Corporation.
04/12/2017 10:26:00,Server,Unknown,UTC adjustment: -4:00
04/12/2017 10:25:59,Server,Unknown,Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU9-GDR) (KB3194722) - 12.0.4487.0 (X64) <nl/>    Oct  5 2016 19:04:21 <nl/>  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation<nl/>    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

**SQL Agent Log**

```
Date,Source,Severity,Message
04/12/2017 10:30:12,,Warning,[000] Request to run job Generate NetAval (from User POSITIVE\ywang) refused because the job is already running from a request by Schedule 1016 (Every 30 Minutes)
04/12/2017 10:26:17,,Warning,[396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect
04/12/2017 10:26:17,,Warning,[475] Database Mail is not enabled for agent notifications.
04/12/2017 10:26:17,,Information,[129] SQLSERVERAGENT starting under Windows NT service control
04/12/2017 10:26:16,,Information,[432] There are 13 subsystems in the subsystems cache
04/12/2017 10:26:15,,Information,[339] Local computer is POS-WEB-SQL2 running Windows NT 6.2 (9200)
04/12/2017 10:26:15,,Information,[310] 8 processor(s) and 32669 MB RAM detected
04/12/2017 10:26:15,,Information,[103] NetLib being used by driver is DBNETLIB; Local host server is
04/12/2017 10:26:15,,Information,[102] SQL Server ODBC driver version 11.00.6518
04/12/2017 10:26:15,,Information,[101] SQL Server POS-WEB-SQL2 version 12.00.4487 (0 connection limit)
04/12/2017 10:26:15,,Information,[000] Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)  Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)  Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)
04/12/2017 10:26:11,,Information,[393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
04/12/2017 10:26:09,,Information,[495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.
04/12/2017 10:26:09,,Information,[100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 12.0.4487.0 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 3564
04/12/2017 09:58:31,,Warning,[098] SQLServerAgent terminated (forcefully)
04/12/2017 09:58:31,,Information,[000] Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)  Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)  Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)
04/12/2017 09:58:30,,Error,[311] Thread 'JobInvocationEngine' (ID 1468) is still running
04/12/2017 09:58:30,,Error,[240] 1 engine thread(s) failed to stop after 2 seconds of waiting
04/12/2017 09:58:28,,Information,[131] SQLSERVERAGENT service stopping due to a stop request from a user<c/> process<c/> or the OS...
04/12/2017 09:58:12,,Error,[136] Job Generate Location39 reported: Unable to terminate process 19f8 launched by step 1 of job 0xD8D121C1B6A6F8409EF65DC99AFE3D67 (reason: Access is denied)
04/12/2017 09:56:41,,Warning,[396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect
04/12/2017 09:56:41,,Warning,[475] Database Mail is not enabled for agent notifications.
04/12/2017 09:56:41,,Information,[129] SQLSERVERAGENT starting under Windows NT service control
04/12/2017 09:56:40,,Information,[432] There are 13 subsystems in the subsystems cache
04/12/2017 09:56:39,,Information,[339] Local computer is POS-WEB-SQL2 running Windows NT 6.2 (9200)
04/12/2017 09:56:39,,Information,[310] 8 processor(s) and 32669 MB RAM detected
04/12/2017 09:56:39,,Information,[103] NetLib being used by driver is DBNETLIB; Local host server is
04/12/2017 09:56:39,,Information,[102] SQL Server ODBC driver version 11.00.6518
04/12/2017 09:56:39,,Information,[101] SQL Server POS-WEB-SQL2 version 12.00.4487 (0 connection limit)
04/12/2017 09:56:39,,Information,[000] Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)  Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)  Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)
04/12/2017 09:56:38,,Information,[393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
04/12/2017 09:56:38,,Information,[495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.
04/12/2017 09:56:38,,Information,[100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 12.0.4487.0 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 5300
```

Comment: Restarted your server to see if it's fixed after another reboot ?

Comment: Rebooted twice and restarted service

Comment: eventlog please too

Comment: eventlog for sqlserver?

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot? What do your event logs say? What specifically is failing? If you want an answer, you need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: What updates happened at 4 AM 4/12/2017?

Comment: @MDMarra Added more info

Comment: @yagmoth555 log has been added

Comment: I feel like the log file is the thing causing the issues here... Would it be normal to pause all trasactions because log file is full?

Comment: I think the lesson learned here is to look at the app before you look into updates as the source of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The log file was too big so I set the recovery mode to simple and reduced the max size.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log